# Image array from ImageDataGenerator does not match image read by CV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use the Image Data Generator with flow from directory to read in
a single 224 X 224 X 3 image titled 1.jpg. The result should be
and identical to the initial image since image size is set to
224 X 244 in flow from directory. I then read in the same image using
cv2. I then compare the array provided by the image data generator
to the array produced by the cv2 read image. I expected them to be
identical but there are NOT. The saved images from the generator
and that saved by cv2 look identical when viewed. To check I printed
the first 10 values in each array and they differ. Why? Code is shown below.

```
dir=r'c:\Temp'# path to  directory containing the sub directory imgtest. 
# sub directory imgtest contains one directory called class1, it contains the image file 1.jpg which is already shape 224 X 224 X 3
test_dir=r'c:\Temp\imgtest' # path to test images directory
save_dir=dir # where the generator will storge the image on disk so it can be viewed later
test_gen=ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1, class_mode='categorical',color_mode='rgb',save_to_dir=save_dir,save_format='jpeg' ,shuffle=False )
data=test_gen.next() # get the next batch from the generator -will be only 1 file which is 1.jpg
image1=data[0][0] # this is the single image 1.jpg provided by the test_gen
print ('for image provided by the generator image shape is ', image1.shape,  '  data type is ',image1.dtype )
img_dir=r'c:\Temp\imgtest\class1'
img_path=os.path.join(img_dir, '1.jpg')
img=cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # read in the original 1.jpg image from c:\Temp\imgtest\class1
img = img.astype('float32') #cv2 reads in data as int8 so convert to float32 to match generator data type
write_loc=os.path.join(dir, 'cvimage.jpg') 
cv2.imwrite(write_loc, img) # save the image to disk so it can be viewed later
print ('for image read in by cv2 image shape is ', img.shape, ' data type is ', img.dtype)
compare_arrays = (image1 == img).all()
if compare_arrays:
    print('arrays are the same')
else:
    print('arrays do not match')
print ('Generator Data,     CV2 Data       Delta')
for i in range (0,10):
    delta=image1[i][0][0] - img [i][0][0]
    print( '  {0}              {1}         {2}'.format(image1[i][0][0],img [i][0][0], delta ))
# the results if running the code are shown below
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
for image provided by the generator image shape is  (224, 224, 3)   data type is  float32
for image read in by cv2 image shape is  (224, 224, 3)  data type is  float32
arrays do not match
Generator Data,     CV2 Data       Delta
  129.0              155.0         -26.0
  141.0              164.0         -23.0
  156.0              174.0         -18.0
  165.0              180.0         -15.0
  173.0              182.0         -9.0
  179.0              183.0         -4.0
  180.0              181.0         -1.0
  181.0              178.0         3.0
  185.0              176.0         9.0
  180.0              170.0         10.0
The original image, generator image and cv2 image are shown in the composite image
[![composite of original, generator and cv2 saved images][1]][1]





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCDDp.jpg
```

Comment: is it possible it's reading the channels differently? just a guess

Comment: that could be it I think cv2 reads images in rbg vs generator rgb. Will check this thanks.

Comment: I'll make this an answer for others who are interested :D

Comment: This is import if you train a model using Image Generator as data source then use the trained model to do predictions where you read in the data using CV2, Predictions will be all messed up

Comment: actually cv2 is format  as bgr forgot that -thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that openCV's standard method for reading images is to read them as BGR, so that blue is the first channel and red is the last. However, most other standard libraries will use RGB (keras's ImageGenerator and PIL.Image, as examples), and so you cannot directly compare cv2 objects with these objects, as they will be different mathematically.

However, after saving to a picture file, this issue should not be an issue, as formatting like `png` is standard.